# Find source of annoying gong sound

Tags: sound-volume

Every now and then I get an annoying gong sound while I'm working. I could turn the sound off, but I would prefer to find out what is producing the sound.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe keep Console (/Applications/Utilities/Console) open in the background and switch to it when you hear the sound.  Hopefully you can spot an event in the Console logs that corresponds with the sound.

Comment: Is it coinciding with you using the keyboard?

Comment: @Buscar: the sound does not seem to be related to using the keyboard.

Comment: ok, then to the next step as described in my answer, open Notification center in the syst pref and disable all "play sound", you have to do it one by one, to find out if it is a Notification you are getting.

Comment: @MrRabbit: I did look on the console, but couldn't spot anything relevant. However, I'm not sure that the console was "open" at the time. I thought that system events would be recorded in the log, whether it was open or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a answer, but I have to use it to explain the process.

It is difficult to find out using the description of a sound like "gong".

You can do some investigating by playing system sounds then reporting which one was it.

To do that go to following folders:

```
/System/Library/Sounds/
/Library/Sounds/
/Users/< username >/Library/Sounds/
```

Now just click on the Space bar to have the QuickView play it.

Start with the System/Library.

I would guess the "gong" is the Sosumi sound. But you can enable the screen flash that will flash the screen when a system sounds occurs..

Open Syst pref and click on Accessibility. Now click on the Audio and select the Flash the Screen.

Also go to your Notification center and turn of sound for apps one by one to find out which one is it, if it comes from there.

Comment: I've been using my computer with the sound turned off. Now I've turned the sound back on again. It may take a few days before I'm in a situation where the problem recurs. When it does, I'll follow your advice and report back. I'll have another look at Notifications. I did try, perhas not effectively, to turn all these off. I was left with the impression that the sound did not come from a notification. But I'll check again.

Comment: Meanwhile, as said, use the screen flash instead of sound to be alerted :)

Comment: what is the point of using screen flash? Sorry to be slow on the uptake.

Comment: I use it while on Mute, to still be informed of a Notification sound.